# WordPress Gutenberg: dynamic block doesn't load the list of posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

In the tutorial "[Creating dynamic blocks](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/)" it is explained that to load the list of recent posts in a Gutenberg block the code to use is this:

```
var el = wp.element.createElement,
    registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    withSelect = wp.data.withSelect;

registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/latest-post', {
    ...

    edit: withSelect( function( select ) {
        return {
            posts: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post' )
        };
    } )( function( props ) {

        if ( ! props.posts ) {
            return "Loading...";
        }

        if ( props.posts.length === 0 ) {
            return "No posts";
        }
        var className = props.className;
        var post = props.posts[ 0 ];

        return el(
            'a',
            { className: className, href: post.link },
            post.title.rendered
        );
    } ),

    ...
} );
```

I've tried this code, but the block always shows "Loading...".

It seems that `props.posts` is always `null` or `undefined` and that the query never returns anything.

Obviously, using the built-in Recent Articles block of WordPress all works well and the list is loaded correctly.

Checking the [code of the built-in block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts/edit.js#L192-L201), it seems using the exact same selctor (also with some more parameters coming from the configuration of the block itself):

```
...

export default withSelect( ( select, props ) => {
    const { postsToShow, order, orderBy, categories } = props.attributes;
    const { getEntityRecords } = select( 'core' );
    const latestPostsQuery = pickBy( {
        categories,
        order,
        orderby: orderBy,
        per_page: postsToShow,
    }, ( value ) => ! isUndefined( value ) );
    return {
        latestPosts: getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post', latestPostsQuery ),
    };
} )( LatestPostsEdit );
```

Any ideas about what maybe happening?

How can I debug the issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution this? I'm facing the same issue and can't work out what's causing it.